# Convert speech to text in flutter for desktop(Windows) application

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, flutter-desktop

I am developing a cross platform application in flutter and cannot find any sources for converting speech to text in desktop(windows).

I tried using packages like [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text)

I even tried [google_speech](https://pub.dev/packages/google_speech) in which it require an audio file to transcribe it to text. But, I could not find any package for taking microphone input in windows so that I can pass it to an API and get the text.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use https://pub.dev/packages/record to record your audio and then send APi request

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: No, I have no affiliation or connection with the service mentioned